# C function substr, PHP extension, strncpy wrong length

Tags: php, c, function

My `php_substr` function should set `kpart` to a33c5b4b58b26d9f however it instead sets it to a33c5b4b58b26d9fìÿ?ê¬¯wÿÿÿÿ®w.

Any ideas?

```
long ks;
char *kpart1;

ks = 16;
php_substr("a33c5b4b58b26d9f78293df1c5d5a3bf", &kpart1, 0, ks); // a33c5b4b58b26d9fìÿ?ê¬¯wÿÿÿÿ®w

char *php_substr(char *str, char **ptr, long f, long l)
{
    int str_len = strlen(str);

    if (!l) {
        l=0;
    }

    if (l!=0) {
        if ((l < 0 && -l > str_len)) {
            return FALSE;
        } else if (l > str_len) {
            l = str_len;
        }
    } else {
        l = str_len;
    }

    if (f > str_len) {
        return FALSE;
    } else if (f < 0 && -f > str_len) {
        f = 0;
    }

    if (l < 0 && (l + str_len - f) < 0) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (f < 0) {
        f = str_len + f;
        if (f < 0) {
            f = 0;
        }
    }

    if (l < 0) {
        l = (str_len - f) + l;
        if (l < 0) {
            l = 0;
        }
    }

    if (f >= str_len) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ((f + l) > str_len) {
        l = str_len - f;
    }

    strncpy(*ptr,str+f,l);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edited to use malloc and included full working code!**

I tried the zend engine emalloc however this didn't seem to work

```
long ks;
char *kpart1;

ks = 16;
kpart1 = php_substr("a33c5b4b58b26d9f78293df1c5d5a3bf", 0, ks); // a33c5b4b58b26d9f

char *php_substr(char *str, long f, long l)
{
    int str_len = strlen(str);
    unsigned char *buffer;

    if (l!=0) {
        if ((l < 0 && -l > str_len)) {
            return FALSE;
        } else if (l > str_len) {
            l = str_len;
        }
    } else {
        l = str_len;
    }

    if (f > str_len) {
        return FALSE;
    } else if (f < 0 && -f > str_len) {
        f = 0;
    }

    if (l < 0 && (l + str_len - f) < 0) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (f < 0) {
        f = str_len + f;
        if (f < 0) {
            f = 0;
        }
    }

    if (l < 0) {
        l = (str_len - f) + l;
        if (l < 0) {
            l = 0;
        }
    }

    if (f >= str_len) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if ((f + l) > str_len) {
        l = str_len - f;
    }

    buffer = (char*)malloc(l+1);
    strncpy(buffer,str+f,l);
    buffer[l]='\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `strncpy` won't correctly nul terminate string if it exceeds available length? I don't know if it's the problem, but people  usually don't know that about `strncpy`.

Comment: `php_substr(key1, &kpart1, 0, ks/2);` you can't use `&kpart1` like that as `kpart1` does not point to a valid memory buffer. So when you use it as the `dest` parameter in `strncpy(*ptr,str+f,l)` you are causing Undefined Behaviour. `kpart1` either needs to be assigned the result of a `malloc` call or needs to be a statically allocated `char` array.

Comment: See the first comment by @user694733. Your `buffer` is not nul terminated. do instead something like `buffer = malloc(l+1); n = strncpy(buffer, str+f, l); buffer[n]=0;`. That is, explicitly nul terminate.

Comment: regarding this line: `  if (!l) {
        l=0;
    }`  the only way for that `if()` to be true is if `l` already contains 0.  Suggest removing that code block

Comment: regarding the posted code.  It fails to compile, even after prefixing with `#include <stdio.h>  #include <stdbool.h>  #include <string.h>`

Comment: regarding the edit about `malloc()`.  1) in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() and family of functions,  the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.   Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.   2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trimming out all the testing of the parameters

After editing into a file that compiles/links/runs

this is the resulting code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define FALSE (0)

char *php_substr(char *str, char **ptr, long f, long l)
{
    strncpy(*ptr,str+f,(size_t)l);
    return 0;
}

int main( void )
{
    long int ks = 16;
    char *kpart1;

    php_substr("a33c5b4b58b26d9f78293df1c5d5a3bf", &kpart1, 0, ks); // a33c5b4b58b26d9fìÿ?ê¬¯wÿÿÿÿ®w
    printf( "%s\n", kpart1);
}
```

Notice that the char pointer: `kpart1` is not initialized to point to any specific location.

(in this case it contains whatever trash was on the stack.  If it were a global variable, it would contian NULL.)

The call to `strncpy()` is trying to copy the first 16 bytes of the passed in constant to where ever `kpart1` happens to be pointing.

The strncpy() results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

I did not perform an analysis on the manipulation of the passed in variables `f` and `l`.

Suggest, as you found, that the pointer: `kpart1` needs to be initialized to point to some allocated memory, where that allocated memory needs to be at least l-f+1 in length.